# autolayout constraints not working correctly when adding them programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

this is my view

[image]

the black area is a view, called `containerView` that has the following constrains

[image]

i want to add a uitableView to it dyrnamically, i did this:

```
 func setConstraintsForTableView(tableView: UITableView){

        self.containerView.addSubview(tableView)

        let bottomConstraint = tableView.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.containerView.bottomAnchor)
        let leftConstraint = tableView.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.containerView.leftAnchor)
        let rightConstraint = tableView.rightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.containerView.rightAnchor)
        let topConstraint = tableView.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.containerView.topAnchor)
        self.containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([bottomConstraint, leftConstraint, rightConstraint, topConstraint])

        self.containerView.layoutIfNeeded()

    }
```

but i got this in the log:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7fe8c9c2ddb0 h=--& v=--& UITableView:0x7fe8cd05c200.midX == + 120>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe8c9e97340 UIView:0x7fe8c9e8aeb0.trailingMargin == UIView:0x7fe8cb304490.trailing>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe8c9e97390 UIView:0x7fe8cb304490.leading == UIView:0x7fe8c9e8aeb0.leadingMargin>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe8c9c2cf70 H:|-(0)-[UITableView:0x7fe8cd05c200](LTR)   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fe8cb304490 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe8c9c2d0c0 UITableView:0x7fe8cd05c200.right == UIView:0x7fe8cb304490.right>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe8cb104c40 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[UIView:0x7fe8c9e8aeb0(375)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe8c9c2d0c0 UITableView:0x7fe8cd05c200.right == UIView:0x7fe8cb304490.right>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2015-12-19 22:12:16.201 GrabATable[2419:218311] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7fe8cb036c70 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fe8c9e956a0(20)]>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7fe8cb0365c0 V:|-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fe8c9e956a0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fe8c9e8aeb0 )>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7fe8cb0363d0 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fe8c9e96410(0)]>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7fe8cb018490 _UILayoutGuide:0x7fe8c9e96410.bottom == UIView:0x7fe8c9e8aeb0.bottom>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7fe8c9c2de50 h=--& v=--& UITableView:0x7fe8cd05c200.midY == + 64>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe8c9e97070 UIImageView:0x7fe8c9e8a160.height == 0.33*UIView:0x7fe8c9e8aeb0.height>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe8c9e97110 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fe8c9e956a0]-(0)-[UIImageView:0x7fe8c9e8a160]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe8c9e972f0 V:[UIImageView:0x7fe8c9e8a160]-(20)-[UIView:0x7fe8cb304490]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe8c9e973e0 V:[UIView:0x7fe8cb304490]-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fe8c9e96410]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe8c9c2cc50 UITableView:0x7fe8cd05c200.bottom == UIView:0x7fe8cb304490.bottom>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe8c9c2d210 V:|-(0)-[UITableView:0x7fe8cd05c200]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fe8cb304490 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe8cb104c90 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UIView:0x7fe8c9e8aeb0(667)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe8c9c2cc50 UITableView:0x7fe8cd05c200.bottom == UIView:0x7fe8cb304490.bottom>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Comment: Any reason for you trying to set them up via code? there is a good reason for the interface builder - because building complex uis (or even simple ones) only via code will not ne fun

Comment: @luk2302 yes i want on the code because i am imitate the tab bar (i don't want to user uitabbarcontroller)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Output of interest:

```
 "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7fe8c9c2ddb0 h=--& v=--& UITableView:0x7fe8cd05c200.midX == + 120>",

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe8c9c2d0c0 UITableView:0x7fe8cd05c200.right == UIView:0x7fe8cb304490.right>
```

You need to set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to false on the tableView. See the [UIView class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) for more detail.

```
tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

From the UIView Class Reference:

> Discussion
>
> If this property’s value is true, the system creates a set
> of constraints that duplicate the behavior specified by the view’s
> autoresizing mask. This also lets you modify the view’s size and
> location using the view’s frame, bounds, or center properties,
> allowing you to create a static, frame-based layout within Auto
> Layout.
>
> Note that the autoresizing mask constraints fully specify the view’s
> size and position; therefore, you cannot add additional constraints to
> modify this size or position without introducing conflicts. If you
> want to use Auto Layout to dynamically calculate the size and position
> of your view, you must set this property to false, and then provide a
> non ambiguous, nonconflicting set of constraints for the view.
>
> By default, the property is set to true for any view you
> programmatically create. If you add views in Interface Builder, the
> system automatically sets this property to false.